# Selenium Webdriver - How to select checkbox, if it has no id?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

So I have this Google Docs survey and there are checkboxes which I want to check with Selenium Webdriver automatically. I tried to locate the element ID but it doesn't have one, only a class name.

```
<label class="docssharedWizToggleLabeledContainer freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioChoice">
    <div class="exportLabelWrapper">
        <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioEl docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl freebirdThemedRadio freebirdThemedRadioDarkerDisabled freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioControl" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseleave:JywGue; touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; keydown:I481le; contextmenu:mg9Pef" jsshadow="" aria-label="Männlich" tabindex="0" data-value="Männlich" aria-describedby="  i5" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="3">
            <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioInk exportInk"></div>
            <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioInnerBox"></div>
            <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioRadioContainer">
                <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle">
                    <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOnRadio exportInnerCircle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="docssharedWizToggleLabeledContent">
            <div class="docssharedWizToggleLabeledPrimaryText">
                <span dir="auto" class="docssharedWizToggleLabeledLabelText exportLabel freebirdFormviewerViewItemsRadioLabel">Männlich</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
<div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioRadioContainer">
    <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle">
        <div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOnRadio exportInnerCircle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"Männlich" is the text of a label which belongs to the checkbox I want to mark, but not the checkbox as an element by itself.

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.name("name"))
driver.findElement(By.id("id"))
```

in this case.

Comment: Please format your HTML code with proper indentation, if you expect anyone to read and understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with xpath: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Something like `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='docssharedWizToggleLabeledContent']/div"))` should work.

Comment: There's nothing in that locator that requires XPath. The equivalent CSS selector would be `div.docssharedWizToggleLabeledContent > div`. CSS selectors are better supported, faster, and easier to read.